# Hey whats wrong with Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: apt

Hey whats wrong with ubuntu 10.10 . Software center is not working. cannot install chrome , flash or anything in command line also .

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! New questions about [end-of-life](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#End_of_Life_.28EOL.29) Ubuntu releases are considered off-topic as per the [Help Center](http://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask). These old releases are unsupported and their use is not recommended. They don't even get updates for newly discovered security vulnerabilities, which makes using them risky. If you install or upgrade to a [supported release](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#Stable) and this question still applies, please flag and/or comment to request it be reopened.

Comment: That you are using a 2010 OS in 2014. Upgrade your system (preferably do a new installation) and you will see how everything works again ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think what is wrong is that Ubuntu 10.10 is a "end-of-life" release at this point, which means it is no longer supported. The servers handling the software packages for Ubuntu 10.10 have been shut down, so you can not install new software from the Software Center.

My best advise is to update your system with a fresh install of Ubuntu, either 12.04 (Long Term Support) or 13.10 (the current release).